# Google Sheet onEdit(e) having permission problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

> ERROR : You do not have permission to call ScriptApp.newTrigger. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp.

Having permission problem to create time based trigger

```
function onEdit(e){
    var sheetName = e.range.getSheet().getName()
    if(sheetName == "Config")
    {
       if(e.range.getRow()==2 && e.range.getColumn()==1){
         createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger()
       } 
    }
}

function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  Logger.log("hello")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For *Simple Triggers*, just running the script within the App Script Web IDE is enough and should prompt you with an authentication popup: [Simple Auth Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PghUt.png).

**However**, to programmatically create new Triggers you need to make sure the onEdit Trigger is [Installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)! This gives you increased permissions to do what you need.

1. We need to open up the dev console to set up an installable trigger.

[image: Installable Trigger Button]

2. We need to create a new trigger tied to our function. *For installable triggers, it is best not to use the default simple trigger `onEdit()` function name.*

[image: Dev Hub Trigger Creation]

**Done!** We should be able to run our functions based on triggers with increased permission scopes.

Comment: Thanks but I had already done this by directly running the function. But I need to run **createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger()** when there is change in column **A2** of **Google Sheet**.

Comment: Sorry, I initially read it wrong and updated my answer shortly after submitting it. Did you try an installable trigger like in the bottom portion of my post?

Comment: can you explain in detail sir.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The process is also outlined on the [Google Documentation for Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).